# Customize WSO2 gateway error messages

Tags: wso2

The WSO2 Gateway returns this format of error message:

```
{"fault":{"code":404,"type":"Status report","message":"Not Found",
 "description":"The requested resource (/account-info/1.0/) is not available."}}
```

But we have a standard format for all error messages that our microservices (which implement the APIs served by WSO2) return. We return a simple JSON object with two fields, error & error_description. So that we can present a consistent interface to our users, in this particular case we would like to see the WSO2 Gateway return exactly this:

```
{"error":"SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE","error_description":
 "The requested resource (/account-info/1.0/) is not available."}
```

and return the HTTP status code only in the header.

Can you please tell me what I need to do to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These error messages are generated from default sequences shipped with WSO2 API Manager.

If the requested resource is not found in API Manager, it will execute the main sequence (`$AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/main.xml`). If you open this file, you will see that the above default error message is generated using a [payload factory mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator) as shown below.

```xml
<payloadFactory>
   <format>
      <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
         <am:code>404</am:code>
         <am:type>Status report</am:type>
         <am:message>Not Found</am:message>
         <am:description>The requested resource (/$1) is not available.</am:description>
      </am:fault>
   </format>
   <args>
      <arg expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX" />
   </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

So if you want to customize the error message, then you need to modify the above payload factory mediator according to your need.

Likewise, if there is any faults occur, the fault sequence (`$AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml`) will be executed. You might want to change the message format there as well.